# How do I add a namespace prefix to each node using TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-namespaces, txmldocument

I used the XML Binding Wizard to create a descendant of TXMLDocument. The files generated by this class would declare the namespace in the root node and create just plain, unadorned nodes for the rest of the document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootNode xmlns="URL" xmlns:xsi="URL" xsi:schemaLocation="URL">
    <SomeNode>
        <AnotherNode>Value</AnotherNode>
    </SomeNode>
</RootNode>
```

I've had no trouble reading or validating this at all. However, the processor where these files are sent now requires each node to have the namespace prefixed in order to process files correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NS:RootNode xmlns:NS="URL" xmlns:xsi="URL" xsi:schemaLocation="URL">
    <NS:SomeNode>
        <NS:AnotherNode>Value</NS:AnotherNode>
    </NS:SomeNode>
</NS:RootNode>
```

How do I accomplish this with my TXMLDocument descendant? I hope it doesn't involve hand editing 10000 lines of generated code.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the solution took a long time to discover but was surprisingly simple.

The code generated by XML Data Binding Wizard will create xml using the default namespace. You can see this by examining the `Get`, `Load` and `New` functions in the generated unit. All three make calls to `GetDocBinding`, passing in `TargetNamespace` as the final parameter. `TargetNamespace` is a global constant string with the URI extracted from the schema or xml document you fed to the Binding Wizard.

Because `TargetNamespace` is assigned to the root element as the default namespace no child elements will have a prefix.

The way to do this:

```
FDocumentName := 
  NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding(
    'ns:DocumentName', // <-- Just add the prefix to the root node.
    TXMLDocumentName,
    TargetNamespace) as IXMLDocumentName;
```

Now the root node will look like:

```
<ns:DocumentName xmlns:ns="URI">
```

And all child nodes will have the prefix when they are created.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution to the problem with multiple namespace: hooking and class helper

```
//
// The original Delphi code is : XMLHookUnit.pas released 2015.09.20
// Last version: 0.1 released 2015.09.20
// The initial developer is Cedomir Plavljanic (cedomir.plavljanic@yahoo.com)
// Copyright (C) 2015-2015 Cedomir Plavljanic
//
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version
//
// This unit is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
//
// This unit hooking 2 methods from XMLDoc.TXMLNode and 1 method from XMLDoc.TXMLNodeList
// Allows use of units created with XML binding wizard with multiple namespace
//
// This is only test
//
//        XML Binding Wizard
//          - change all the names that end with _ (All signature nodes have this problem)
//          - example: TSignatureType_ -> TSignatureType_ds
//
// Usage: add the unit to project
//
// This unit contains variables
//    - ListNameSpace - dictionary for pair prefixes and namespace
//          - in example pair is from XML Schema Definition in UBL 2.1 by Oasis
//            http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/UBL-2.1.html
//          - for own use must changed
//    - DigitalSignatureWithoutPrefix - flag for add or remove digital signature prefix in nodename
//
//
// This unit contains Helper: TXMLNodeListHelper, TXMLNodeHelper
// This unit contains function for hooking TXMLNode and TXMLNodeList
// For hooking in testing using example from Hook Api Library 0.2 [Ring3] By Anskya Email:Anskya@Gmail.com
//  - with litle modification in call function VirtualProtect
//      - flNewProtect used as PAGE_READWRITE
//
// version: 0.1
// can be used with all versions of Delphi that have suport generic TDictionary
// for older versions of Delphi have to ask via e-mail or add support for TDictionary
// I also have a version for Delphi 2007 (XML binding wizard is bad, must be used from newer version of Delphi)
//


unit XMLHookUnit;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

var
////Dictionary for pair prefixes and namespaces in all *.xsd file (without default namespace)
    ListNameSpace : TDictionary<String, String>;
//Include or Exclude ds: prefix in digital signature node
  DigitalSignatureWithoutPrefix : Boolean = True;

//Hook 1 methods from TXMLNodeList and 2 method from TXMLNode
//TXMLNodeList.GetNode
//TXMLNode.RegisterChildNode
//TXMLNode.InternalAddChildNode
//for hooking in testing using example from Hook Api Library 0.2 [Ring3] By Anskya Email:Anskya@Gmail.com
//with litle modification in call function VirtualProtect
//flNewProtect is PAGE_READWRITE
procedure HookXMLNodeLibrary;
//UnHook 1 methods from TXMLNodeList and 2 method from TXMLNode
//TXMLNodeList.GetNode
//TXMLNode.RegisterChildNode
//TXMLNode.InternalAddChildNode
//for unhooking in testing using example from Hook Api Library 0.2 [Ring3] By Anskya Email:Anskya@Gmail.com
//with litle modification in call function VirtualProtect
//flNewProtect is PAGE_READWRITE
procedure UnHookXMLNodeLibrary;

implementation

uses
  System.Types, StrUtils, Variants, HookApiLib, xmldom, XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

const
//namespace for digital signature
  NameSpace_DigitalSignature = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#';

var
//Flag is True if methods from XMLDoc are hooked
  IsHookXMLNodeLibrary : Boolean = False;

type
//access to proteted part in TXMLNodeList
  TXMLNodeListHelp = class(TXMLNodeList);
//access to proteted part in TXMLNode
  TXMLNodeHelp = class(TXMLNode);

//helper for TXMLNodelist
  TXMLNodeListHelper = class helper for TXMLNodeList
  public
//avoid overload trouble
//getnode call wrong findnode function
    function FindNodeHelp(aField: DOMString):IXMLNode;
//find prefix for node in ListNameSpace
    function FindPrefixHelp(aField:DOMString):String;
  end;

//helper function for TXMLNodelist
  TXMLNodeHelper = class helper for TXMLNode
  public
//extract LocalName, Prefix and Namespace based on NodeName
    procedure ExtractFieldPrefixNameSpace(const aNodeName: DOMString; out aField, aPrefix, aNameSpace: DOMString);
  end;

//prototype for hooking TXMLNodeList.GetNode
  TProtoTypeNodeListGetNode = function( const aSelf:TXMLNodeListHelp;
                                        const IndexOrName: OleVariant): IXMLNode;
//prototype for hooking TXMLNode.RegisterChildNode
  TProtoTypeNodeRegisterChildNode = procedure(const aSelf:TXMLNodeHelp;
                                              const aField: DOMString;
                                              const ChildNodeClass: TXMLNodeClass;
                                              const aNameSpace : DOMString);
//prototype for hooking TXMLNode.InternalAddChild
  TProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild = function(const aSelf:TXMLNodeHelp;
                                            const NodeClass: TXMLNodeClass;
                                            const NodeName, NamespaceURI: DOMString;
                                            const Index: Integer): IXMLNode;

var
//Save old address for TXMLNodeList.GetNode
  SavePrototypeGetNode : TProtoTypeNodeListGetNode = nil;
//Save old address for TXMLNode.RegisterChildNode
  SaveProtoTypeRegisterChildNode : TProtoTypeNodeRegisterChildNode = nil;
//Save old address for TXMLNode.InternalAddChild
  SaveProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild : TProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild = nil;

{ TXMLNodeListHelper }

function TXMLNodeListHelper.FindNodeHelp(aField: DOMString): IXMLNode;

var
  aPrefix: string;

begin
  aPrefix := FindPrefixHelp(aField);
  if aPrefix <> '' then Result := FindNode(aPrefix+':'+aField, '');
  if Result = nil then Result := FindNode(aField, '');
end;

function TXMLNodeListHelper.FindPrefixHelp(aField: DOMString): String;

var
  aNodeClass:TNodeClassArray;
  i: Integer;
  aTest:TPair<String,String>;

begin
  Result := '';
  aNodeClass := TXMLNodeHelp(Self.Owner).ChildNodeClasses;
  aField:=ExtractLocalName(aField);
  for i := 0 to Length(aNodeClass)-1 do
    if aNodeClass[i].NodeName = aField then begin
      for aTest in ListNameSpace do begin
        if aTest.Value = aNodeClass[i].NamespaceURI then begin
          Result := aTest.Key;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
      Break;
    end;
end;

{ TXMLNodeHelper }
procedure TXMLNodeHelper.ExtractFieldPrefixNameSpace(const aNodeName : DOMString; out aField, aPrefix, aNameSpace: DOMString);
var
  i: Integer;
  sHelp:DOMString;
  Test:TPair<String,String>;
  Flag : Boolean;

begin
  sHelp := ExtractLocalName(aNodeName);
  aPrefix := '';
  aNameSpace := '';
  Flag := False;
  for i := 0 to Length(ChildNodeClasses) - 1 do begin
    if ChildNodeClasses[i].NodeName = sHelp then begin
      aNameSpace := ChildNodeClasses[i].NamespaceURI;
      for Test in ListNameSpace do begin
        if Test.Value = aNameSpace then begin
          aPrefix := Test.Key;
          Flag := DigitalSignatureWithoutPrefix and (aNameSpace = NameSpace_DigitalSignature);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if (aPrefix = '') or (Flag) then begin
    aField := ExtractLocalName(aNodeName);
    if aNameSpace = '' then aNameSpace := GetNamespaceURI;
  end else
    aField := aPrefix + ':' + ExtractLocalName(aNodeName);
end;


//help function for find namaspase bassed on classname
//last part after underscore in classname is prefix
function GetNameSpace(const ChildNodeClass: TXMLNodeClass): DOMString;

var
  aList : TStringDynArray;

begin
  Result := ChildNodeClass.ClassName;
  aList:=StrUtils.SplitString(Result,'_');
  if Length(aList)>1 then
    ListNameSpace.TryGetValue(aList[Length(aList)-1],Result)
  else
   Result := '';
end;

//replace for TXMLNodeList.GetNode
function GetNodeHelp( const aSelf:TXMLNodeListHelp;
                      const IndexOrName: OleVariant):IXMLNode;

begin
  if VarIsOrdinal(IndexOrName) then
    Result := SavePrototypeGetNode(aSelf,IndexOrName)
  else begin
    Result := aSelf.FindNodeHelp(DOMString(IndexOrName));
    if Result = nil then
      Result := SavePrototypeGetNode(aSelf,IndexOrName);
  end;
end;

//replace for TXMLNode.RegisterChildNode
procedure RegisterChildNodeHelp(const aSelf:TXMLNodeHelp;
                                const aField: DOMString;
                                const ChildNodeClass: TXMLNodeClass;
                                const aNameSpace : DOMString);

var
  hNameSpace: DOMString;

begin
  if aNameSpace<>'' then
    hNameSpace := aNameSpace
  else begin
    hNameSpace := GetNameSpace(ChildNodeClass);
    if hNameSpace = '' then hNameSpace := aSelf.GetNamespaceURI;
  end;
  SaveProtoTypeRegisterChildNode(aSelf, aField, ChildNodeClass, hNameSpace);
end;

//replace for TXMLNode.InternalAddChild
function InternalAddChildHelp(const aSelf:TXMLNodeHelp;
                              const NodeClass: TXMLNodeClass;
                              const NodeName, NamespaceURI: DOMString;
                              const Index: Integer): IXMLNode;

var
  aField, aPrefix, aNameSpace:DOMString;

begin
  aSelf.ExtractFieldPrefixNameSpace(NodeName, aField, aPrefix, aNameSpace);
  Result := SaveProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild(aSelf, NodeClass, aField, aNameSpace, Index);
end;


procedure HookXMLNodeLibrary;

begin
  if IsHookXMLNodeLibrary then Exit;

  @SavePrototypeGetNode := HookCode(@TXMLNodeListHelp.GetNode, @GetNodeHelp);
  @SaveProtoTypeRegisterChildNode := HookCode(@TXMLNodeHelp.RegisterChildNode, @RegisterChildNodeHelp);
  @SaveProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild := HookCode(@TXMLNodeHelp.InternalAddChild, @InternalAddChildHelp);
  IsHookXMLNodeLibrary := True;
end;

procedure UnHookXMLNodeLibrary;

begin
  if not IsHookXMLNodeLibrary then Exit;

  UnHookCode(@SavePrototypeGetNode);
  UnHookCode(@SaveProtoTypeRegisterChildNode);

  UnHookCode(@SaveProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild);

  SavePrototypeGetNode := nil;
  SaveProtoTypeRegisterChildNode := nil;
  SaveProtoTypeNodeInternalAddChild := nil;

  IsHookXMLNodeLibrary := False;
end;

//Dictionary for prefixes and namespaces
procedure AddNameSpace;

begin
    ListNameSpace.Add('xsd','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
    ListNameSpace.Add('cac','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('cbc','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('ccts','urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('ext','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('udt','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnqualifiedDataTypes-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('qdt','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDataTypes-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('ccts-cct','urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:CoreComponentTypeSchemaModule:2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('cct','urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:CoreComponentTypeSchemaModule:2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('sig','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('sac','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2');
    ListNameSpace.Add('ds','http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
    ListNameSpace.Add('sbc','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2');
  ListNameSpace.Add('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

end;

initialization
  HookXMLNodeLibrary;
    ListNameSpace := TDictionary<String,String>.Create;
    AddNameSpace;
finalization
  UnHookXMLNodeLibrary;
    ListNameSpace.DisposeOf;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the answer above, sometimes you may need the namespace prefix to continue in repeating child nodes (the type you create using the Add() or Insert() functions). In that case you will need to add the prefix and colon before the child class name in the first argument of RegisterChildNode() and the ItemTag variable to match. (See example below, with "CPR:" being used as the namespace prefix)

```
void __fastcall TXMLeCPR_payrollInfo_employees::AfterConstruction(void)
{
  RegisterChildNode(System::UnicodeString("CPR:employee"), __classid(TXMLeCPR_payrollInfo_employees_employee));
  ItemTag = "CPR:employee";
  ItemInterface = __uuidof(IXMLeCPR_payrollInfo_employees_employee);
  Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeCollection::AfterConstruction();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solution of Cedomir Plavljanic, I created unit hooking delphi methods and allows easy use units created with Delphi XML Binding Wizard with multiple namespace and proper prefixes.

[XMLDocHelper](https://github.com/miszellek/XMLDocHelper)

```
unit XMLDocHelper;

(*
  (CreateCollection\(.+?,.+?, ')(.+?)\)
  \1tns:\2\)
  RegisterChildNode('
  RegisterChildNode('tns:
  ChildNodes['
  ChildNodes['tns:
  ItemTag := '
  ItemTag := 'tns:
*)

interface

uses DDetours, System.Variants, System.Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils, Xml.XMLDoc, Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.xmldom;

type
  TXMLNodeHelp = class(TXMLNode);
  TXMLNodeListHelp = class(TXMLNodeList);
  TXMLNodeCollectionHelp = class(TXMLNodeCollection);

type
  TXMLNodeHelper = class helper for TXMLNode
  public
    function _FindNamespaceURI(const TagOrPrefix: DOMString): DOMString;
  end;

var
  TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode: procedure(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; const TagName: DOMString; ChildNodeClass: TXMLNodeClass; NamespaceURI: DOMString = '') = nil;
  TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection: function(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; const CollectionClass: TXMLNodeCollectionClass; const ItemInterface: TGuid; const ItemTag: DOMString; ItemNS: DOMString = ''): TXMLNodeCollection = nil;
  TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild: function(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; NodeClass: TXMLNodeClass; const NodeName, NamespaceURI: DOMString; Index: Integer): IXMLNode;
  TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode: function(const aSelf: TXMLNodeListHelp; const aIndexOrName: OleVariant): IXMLNode = nil;
  TrampolineXMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem: function(const aSelf: TXMLNodeCollectionHelp; const Node: IXMLNode): Boolean;

implementation

procedure XMLNode_RegisterChildNodeHooked(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; const TagName: DOMString; ChildNodeClass: TXMLNodeClass; NamespaceURI: DOMString = '');
begin
  if IsPrefixed(TagName) and (NamespaceURI = '') then
    TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode(aSelf, TagName, ChildNodeClass, aSelf._FindNamespaceURI(TagName))
  else
    TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode(aSelf, TagName, ChildNodeClass, NamespaceURI);
end;

function XMLNode_CreateCollectionHooked(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; const CollectionClass: TXMLNodeCollectionClass; const ItemInterface: TGuid; const ItemTag: DOMString; ItemNS: DOMString = ''): TXMLNodeCollection;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if IsPrefixed(ItemTag) and (ItemNS = '') then
    Result := TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection(aSelf, CollectionClass, ItemInterface, ItemTag, aSelf._FindNamespaceURI(ItemTag));
  if Result = nil then
    Result := TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection(aSelf, CollectionClass, ItemInterface, ItemTag, ItemNS);
end;

function XMLNode_InternalAddChildHooked(const aSelf: TXMLNodeHelp; NodeClass: TXMLNodeClass; const NodeName, NamespaceURI: DOMString; Index: Integer): IXMLNode;
var
  NS: string;
begin
  NS := aSelf._FindNamespaceURI(NodeName);
  if NS = '' then
    NS := NamespaceURI;
  Result := TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild(aSelf, NodeClass, NodeName, NS, Index)
end;

function XMLNodeList_GetNodeHooked(const aSelf: TXMLNodeListHelp; const aIndexOrName: OleVariant): IXMLNode;
begin
  if VarIsOrdinal(aIndexOrName) then
    Result := TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode(aSelf, aIndexOrName)
  else
  begin
    if IsPrefixed(aIndexOrName) then
      Result := aSelf.FindNode(ExtractLocalName(aIndexOrName), aSelf.Owner._FindNamespaceURI(aIndexOrName));
    if Result = nil then
      Result := TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode(aSelf, aIndexOrName);
  end;
end;

function XMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem(const aSelf: TXMLNodeCollectionHelp; const Node: IXMLNode): Boolean;

const
  AdjustIndex = 1 - Low(string);

type
  TStringSplitOption = (ssNone, ssRemoveEmptyEntries);
  TStringSplitOptions = set of TStringSplitOption;
  TDOMStringDynArray = array of DOMString;

  function SplitString(const S: DOMString; Delimiter: WideChar; const StringSplitOptions: TStringSplitOptions = []): TDOMStringDynArray;
  var
    LInputLength, LResultCapacity, LResultCount, LCurPos, LSplitStartPos: Integer;
  begin
    { Get the current capacity of the result array }
    LResultCapacity := Length(Result);
    { Reset the number of results already set }
    LResultCount := 0;
    { Start at the first character }
    LSplitStartPos := 1;
    { Save the length of the input }
    LInputLength := Length(S);
    { Step through the entire string }
    for LCurPos := 1 to LInputLength do
    begin
      { Find a delimiter }
      if S[LCurPos - AdjustIndex] = Delimiter then
      begin
        { Is the split non-empty, or are empty strings allowed? }
        if (LSplitStartPos < LCurPos) or not(ssRemoveEmptyEntries in StringSplitOptions) then
        begin
          { Split must be added - is there enough capacity in the result array? }
          if LResultCount = LResultCapacity then
          begin
            { Grow the result array - make it slightly more than double the
              current size }
            LResultCapacity := LResultCapacity * 2 + 8;
            SetLength(Result, LResultCapacity);
          end;
          { Set the string }
          SetString(Result[LResultCount], PWideChar(@S[LSplitStartPos - AdjustIndex]), LCurPos - LSplitStartPos);
          { Increment the result count }
          Inc(LResultCount);
        end;
        { Set the next split start position }
        LSplitStartPos := LCurPos + 1;
      end;
    end;
    { Add the final split }
    if (LSplitStartPos <= LInputLength) or not(ssRemoveEmptyEntries in StringSplitOptions) then
    begin
      { Correct the output length }
      if LResultCount + 1 <> LResultCapacity then
        SetLength(Result, LResultCount + 1);
      { Set the string }
      SetString(Result[LResultCount], PWideChar(@S[LSplitStartPos - AdjustIndex]), LInputLength - LSplitStartPos + 1);
    end
    else
    begin
      { No final split - correct the output length }
      if LResultCount <> LResultCapacity then
        SetLength(Result, LResultCount);
    end;
  end;

var
  I: Integer;
  LocalName: DOMString;
  FItemTags: TDOMStringDynArray;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Supports(Node, aSelf.ItemInterface) then
  begin
    LocalName := ExtractLocalName(Node.NodeName);
    Result := (LocalName = ExtractLocalName(aSelf.ItemTag)); // here is the Bug
    // If FItemTag has semicolons in it, then there are multiple valid names and we must check each one
    if not Result and (Pos(';', aSelf.ItemTag) > 0) then
    begin
      FItemTags := SplitString(aSelf.ItemTag, ';', [ssRemoveEmptyEntries]);
      for I := Low(FItemTags) to High(FItemTags) do
        if LocalName = ExtractLocalName(FItemTags[I]) then // and here is the Bug
        begin
          Result := True;
          Break;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TXMLNodeHelper._FindNamespaceURI(const TagOrPrefix: DOMString): DOMString;
begin
  Result := FindNamespaceURI(TagOrPrefix);
end;

initialization

@TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode := InterceptCreate(@TXMLNodeHelp.RegisterChildNode, @XMLNode_RegisterChildNodeHooked);
@TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection := InterceptCreate(@TXMLNodeHelp.CreateCollection, @XMLNode_CreateCollectionHooked);
@TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild := InterceptCreate(@TXMLNodeHelp.InternalAddChild, @XMLNode_InternalAddChildHooked);
@TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode := InterceptCreate(@TXMLNodeListHelp.GetNode, @XMLNodeList_GetNodeHooked);
@TrampolineXMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem := InterceptCreate(@TXMLNodeCollectionHelp.IsCollectionItem, @XMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem);

finalization

if Assigned(TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode) then
begin
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode);
  TrampolineXMLNode_RegisterChildNode := nil;
end;

if Assigned(TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection) then
begin
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection);
  TrampolineXMLNode_CreateCollection := nil;
end;

if Assigned(TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild) then
begin
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild);
  TrampolineXMLNode_InternalAddChild := nil;
end;

if Assigned(TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode) then
begin
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode);
  TrampolineXMLNodeList_GetNode := nil;
end;

if Assigned(TrampolineXMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem) then
begin
  InterceptRemove(@TrampolineXMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem);
  TrampolineXMLNodeCollection_IsCollectionItem := nil;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score -1):

[add namespace + prefix to XML using XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803063/add-namespace-prefix-to-xml-using-xsl)

The accepted answer shows how XSL can be used to add namespace prefixes.

Quote:

---

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:login="http://my.ns.uri">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="login:{name()}" namespace="http://my.ns.uri">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<login:data xmlns:login="http://my.ns.uri">
   <login:token>
      <login:sessionId>12345</login:sessionId>
      <login:userId>john</login:userId>
      <login:moreInfo>
         <login:bla> .....
         </login:bla>
      </login:moreInfo>
   </login:token>
</login:data>
```