# Lazarus with xml namespaces

Tags: xml, lazarus

I use DOM to create an xml file.  Everything is generated correctly, but I have no idea how to set namespaces. I saw lot solutions (for example [How do I add a namespace prefix to each node using TXMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989012/how-do-i-add-a-namespace-prefix-to-each-node-using-txmldocument)), but any not work in Lazarus. I need generate XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:string xmlns:etd="uri "    xmlns:tns="uri" xmlns:xsi="uri">
<tns:RootNode >
<tns:SomeNode>
     <tns:AnotherNode>Value</NS:AnotherNode>
 </tns:SomeNode>
</tns:RootNode>
```

I try this:

```
TRY
Doc := TXMLDocument.Create;
doc.CreateElementNS('tns:','uri');
RootNode := Doc.CreateElement('Element');
Doc.Appendchild(RootNode);
....
....
writeXMLFile(Doc,xmlfile);

finally
Doc.Free;
end; 

RootNode:= Doc.DocumentElement;
```

without any result Doc don't have a uri and tns

Please help me!