# Need to know the functionality of the XSLT methods and TAGS

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, transform

I'm trying to add a namespace prefix while transform the XML using the XSLT. At first I was trying `<app:ABC>` in the xml file and was getting exception related to the **not bind** (forget it not sure about the exception) Then I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803063/add-namespace-prefix-to-xml-using-xsl) but I'm having some trouble while understanding this. I have the following question which are as follow:

1. `<xsl:copy>` - what is it use for. According to my understanding this is used for copy the element. Does it only copy the root element or also the following child?
2. `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">` - I'm not sure how this process works, how can I use the select attribute? `node()` what it's used for? the also the `@*` sign. I'm assuming `|` sign is used for OR. If not, please guide me.
3. `<xsl:element name="app:{name()}" namespace="http://my.ns.uri">` - According to my understanding the **element** tag is used to add a node (element) in the XML. Here again I'm confused with the `name()` method. What it's used for? Can we only used the element name instead of it? and does namespace attribute is necessary? Please confirm.
4. `<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>` No idea about this. Please guide me why we are just using this or necessary.

All comments and suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you referenced is a modified [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which matches XML nodes and applies templates to each of the attributes and nodes in the document and simply copies them to the output.

Unless a more specific template is available, the identity template will match, copy the context node, and then apply templates to any attributes or child nodes() of the matched item.

1. [`<xsl:copy>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying)

> The xsl:copy element provides an easy way of copying the current node.
>   Instantiating the `xsl:copy` element creates a copy of the current node.
>   The namespace nodes of the current node are automatically copied as
>   well, but the attributes and children of the node are not
>   automatically copied. The content of the `xsl:copy` element is a
>   template for the attributes and children of the created node; the
>   content is instantiated only for nodes of types that can have
>   attributes or children (i.e. root nodes and element nodes).

2. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` - Selects any attributes or child nodes from the context node and applies templates, looking for the most specific match from the templates that are defined in the stylesheet.

   - `|` is a union operator. It acts kind of like an OR and kind of like an AND, depending on how you think about it. If there are duplicate nodes in the left hand or right hand side of the operator, the result will be a unique list of items with duplicates removed.
   - `@*` will select any attribute attached to the context node
   - `node()` will select any element, text node, processing-instruction, or comment that is a child of the context element. An equivalent expression would be `*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()`.
3. `<xsl:element name="app:{name()}" namespace="http://my.ns.uri">`

   - [`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element)

> The `xsl:element` element allows an element to be created with a
>   computed name. The expanded-name of the element to be created is
>   specified by a required name attribute and an optional namespace
>   attribute. The content of the `xsl:element` element is a template for
>   the attributes and children of the created element.
>
> The name attribute is interpreted as an attribute value template. It
>   is an error if the string that results from instantiating the
>   attribute value template is not a QName. An XSLT processor may signal
>   the error; if it does not signal the error, then it must recover by
>   making the the result of instantiating the `xsl:element` element be the
>   sequence of nodes created by instantiating the content of the
>   `xsl:element` element, excluding any initial attribute nodes. If the
>   namespace attribute is not present then the QName is expanded into an
>   expanded-name using the namespace declarations in effect for the
>   `xsl:element` element, including any default namespace declaration.
>
> If the namespace attribute is present, then it also is interpreted as
>   an attribute value template. The string that results from
>   instantiating the attribute value template should be a URI reference.
>   It is not an error if the string is not a syntactically legal URI
>   reference. If the string is empty, then the expanded-name of the
>   element has a null namespace URI. Otherwise, the string is used as the
>   namespace URI of the expanded-name of the element to be created. The
>   local part of the QName specified by the name attribute is used as the
>   local part of the expanded-name of the element to be created.

- [`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) is being used to obtain the name of the context node (the one being transformed). It's "base name" is concatenated with the namespace prefix which will be bound to the namespace declared in the `@namespace` attribute. The template could (and probably should) use [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name), which will be the "base" name of the element without the namespace prefix. Since the source document being transformed did not have any namespace-prefixes, `name()` and `local-name()` will return the same value.
- With almost every XSLT processor (I have not encountered one that does not behave this way), if the namespace has been declared in your XSLT and you use it's namespace-prefix in the element name constructor, you don't have to explicitly declare the namespace with the `@namespace` attribute. The XSLT processor will bind the element to the namespace that matches the namespace-prefix declared in the styleshet.

> XSLT processors may make use of the prefix of the QName specified in
>   the name attribute when selecting the prefix used for outputting the
>   created element as XML; however, they are not required to do so.

4. `<xsl:copy-of selecct="namespace::*"/>` - this explicitly copies all of the namespace nodes on the context node. It's generally not necessary.